# I can't get my redirect to work if the user's ip is in the database

Tags: php, redirect

I am creating a welcome page for my site that will be displayed to the user if they haven't already been on the website.

I have created a landing page called welcome that will add the users ip to a table in a database when they visit my website.

On my homepage I am trying to make it so that if the users ip is in the database then it won't redirect them to the welcome page and if the ip is not in the database then it will redirect them to the welcome page and on that page their ip will be added to the database so that they do not get redirected next time they visit the site.

Here is my code so far, when I go onto the site it doesn't redirect me to the landing page and I am not sure what the issue is:

```
<?

$ip = getenv('HTTP_CLIENT_IP')?:
getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR')?:
getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED')?:
getenv('HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR')?:
getenv('HTTP_FORWARDED')?:
getenv('REMOTE_ADDR');

$query = "SELECT * FROM landing WHERE ip = $ip"; 
$result = mysql_query($query);

$num = mysql_num_rows($result);

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){

if($num == '0') {

header("Location: https://tantami.com/welcome/index.php");

} else {



}


}



?>
```

Comment: IP addresses are not always statically assigned to a particular physical address ( ie house ) so a user could visit on Monday, then return on Tuesday with a different IP address - you then have the same user with two addresses. Also, some locations have a single gateway IP address ( I note your code above looking for the `FORWARDED_FOR` which typifies a proxy ) so again a potential issue. Perhaps a combination of IP and a cookie might be better? As for you not being redirected - I presume your IP is already in the db?

Comment: I have removed my ip from the database but I am still not being redirect. I will have a look at doing it with cookies though as I didn't think about the IP not being static. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If enough to check in the database if there's a record of that ip:

```
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

$query = "SELECT id FROM landing WHERE ip = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($ip) . "' LIMIT 1"; 

$result = mysql_query($query);

$num = mysql_num_rows($result);

//if the ip is not in the database make the redirect 

if($num == 0) {

    header("Location: https://tantami.com/welcome/index.php");

}
```

Answer (score 0):

your problem was in your query.

you should add  (Apostrophe)  before and after of all string in query.

(i also change your select * query yo select count(*))

```
$ip = getenv('HTTP_CLIENT_IP')?:
getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR')?:
getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED')?:
getenv('HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR')?:
getenv('HTTP_FORWARDED')?:
getenv('REMOTE_ADDR');

$query = "SELECT count(*) as nums FROM landing WHERE ip = '$ip'"; 
$result = mysql_query($query);


$row= mysql_fetch_array($result);
$num=$row['nums'];
if($num == '0') {

header("Location: https://tantami.com/welcome/index.php");

} else {



}
```

Comment: why is this a solution? Please explain

Comment: cheers. Although I hate to be pedantic but the symbol is actually a single quote rather than an apostrophe.

Comment: Out of curiosity, how come you set the count as a SQL part rather than using the MySQL function?

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues going on here, in a rough order of importance with regards to your problem they are:

- Encase your value in quotes. so `SELECT * FROM landing WHERE ip = '$ip'` notice the `$ip` is encased, as is required for strings in a Query.
- Please start to use MySQLi rather than the deprecated MySQL. This is more secure, and still supported by both MySQL and PHP. research on StackOverflow how to make the pretty easy transfer.
- Your mysql_num_rows is a integer count so should not be in quotes. So set `if (mysqli_num_rows($result) == 0 )` .
- Immediately after your `header()` you should add a die or end command such as `exit;`
- PHP should ideally always open with a full `<?php` declaration.
- I'll say it again, use MySQLi.
- The `$ip` should be escaped in this script, specifically, use `mysqli_real_escape_string()` or even use a REGEX pattern to remove any non valid characters from the `$ip`, before testing in the SQL query.

  Code:

  `$ip = preg_replace("/[^0-9:.]/","",$ip);`